# Gradle error in Corda springboot integration

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, corda

I am trying to integrate SpringBoot webserver with Corda application in IntelliJ IDE. I removed contents of Cordapp folder and added my springboot src folder and build.gradle. I also modified root build.gradle. However on refreshing dependencies I am facing issues in getting dependency resolved.

I am getting the error:

```
Warning:<i><b>root project '<project-name>': Unable to build Kotlin project configuration</b>
Details: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':integrationTestCompileClasspath'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
Required by:
    project : > project :cordapp</i>
```

These are the build.gradle files:

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
    ext.corda_release_version = '3.1-corda'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.1.0'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordapp:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:cordformation:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
        classpath "net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:$corda_gradle_plugins_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/test"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
        kotlin {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/kotlin')
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"

    // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies
    // Specify your CorDapp's dependencies below, including dependent CorDapps.
    // We've defined Cash as a dependent CorDapp as an example.
    cordapp project(":cordapp")
    cordapp project(":cordapp-contracts-states")
    cordapp "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: []) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" // Required for passing named arguments to your flow via the shell.
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        languageVersion = "1.1"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        javaParameters = true   // Useful for reflection.
    }
}

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pPort 10002
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        webPort 10007
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        webPort 10010
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
}

task runTemplateClient(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'io.app.application.Application'
    args 'localhost:10006'
}
```

Cordapp build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.14'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea' //legacy technique of adding plugin
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'


lombok {
    version = '1.18.0'
    sha256 = ""
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/dev"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "config/test"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-parameters" // Required for passing named arguments to your flow via the shell.
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:4.2.0")
    compile("com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:4.2.0")
    compile("com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.2.0")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    //compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'



    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"
    cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"

    testCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"

    // CorDapp dependencies
    // Specify your CorDapp's dependencies below, including dependent CorDapps.
    // We've defined Cash as a dependent CorDapp as an example.
    cordapp project(":cordapp-contracts-states")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
```

As mentioned in the logs. I believe the version of `spring-boot-starter-web` is required.

In your build script add `ext.spring_boot_version = 'Your prefered version'`
and change the dependency like below:

`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$spring_boot_version")`

This way, it shouldn't throw `ModuleVersionNotFoundException`

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick and libraries were successfully imported. However, I cant get why its not able to fetch the version automatically as suggested in springboot official documentation. Also, these gradle files did work successfully in silos when I made isolated springboot app through gradle.